# Passing Variable to jQuery Modal Form

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

This may be simple, or impossible, but either way, I want to pass a table row name to a modal dialog form via jquery.

```
$('.activate_modal').click(function(){

            var rowid = $(this).attr('name');

            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );

        });
```

I am dynamically creating rows via PHP, and on click opens a jquery modal window, I need to pass an id (the var rowid) to the form so it knows what rows is calling the function. is this possible?

Comment: PHP comes before javascript, so yes it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `data()` method for this.

i.e.

```
var rowid = $(this).attr('name');
$( "#dialog-form" ).data('rowID', rowid); // set the data to be passed
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
```

And when you need to access the value, you can access it like:

```
var passedInRowId = $( "#dialog-form" ).data('rowID'); // get the data that was passed
```

---

For filling in a form field that appears inside the popup.

var rowid = $(this).attr('name');
$( "#dialog-form" ).data('rowID', rowid); // set the data to be passed

// fill it in here before diaplaying the dialog
// NOTE: if this is the only place you need the rowid on, you dont need to use data() at all
$('#yourformfield').val(rowid);

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );

Comment: Data: `<div id="dialog-form" data-rowID="<?php //get row id ?>"></div>`

Comment: Awesome, thank you, can you take me one step further and tell me how to echo this rowid in a standard html form as it pops up?

Comment: @bobthyasian how can php get a javascript variable as stated?

Comment: @savagenoob - Once you've retrieved the `passedInRowId` like shown above, you can do a `$('#yourelement').val(passedInRowId);` on the element you to have this filled in.

Comment: @techfoobar  like : <div id="dialog-form" title="Create Soft Quote">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
 <script>var passedInRowId = $( "#dialog-form" ).data('rowID'); 
 $('#yourelement').val(passedInRowId);
 </script>
    <form> etc... ?

Comment: No. You should fill it in *after* setting the rowid using `.data()` - I'll post a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a bit more helpful.

```
<?php $rowID = /* Do DB Query */; $rowMessage = /* Do DB Query */; ?>

<span class="activate_modal" data-rowID="<?php echo $rowID; ?>">Activate</span>

<div id="<?php echo $rowID; ?>" class="modal"><?php $rowMessage; ?></div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.activate_modal').click(function(){
            var rowid = $(this).data('rowID');
            $('#'+rowid+'.modal').dialog('open');
        });
    });    
</script>
```